# How can I run Jupiter test classes in a specific order?

Tags: junit5, junit-jupiter

A test run failed on the build server but it passes locally, due to some issues in the tests and differences in the order of files returned by the OS.

What is the best way to run tests locally in the same order as the build server to debug the issue? (order of whole test classes matters much more than order of test methods. also it's ok if the solution is a complete hack)

Comment: Jupiter is meant for writing unit tests, which, by definition, should be independent from each other, so I don't think there's a way to do what you want. Not without writing some sort of custom test runner.

Comment: sure. how to write a custom test runner?

Comment: for temporary debugging, you can use `@TestMethodOrder` from JUnit 5. You can find an example usage here: https://rieckpil.de/five-junit-5-features-you-might-not-know-yet/

Comment: I'll need to get a full custom test runner or something working since the class order causes issues, not the method order.

Comment: Looks like there is currently an on-going discussion for class ordering: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1948